# ASP.NET MVC 5 Traditional Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

When I debug it, the Product and Subcategory link works fine, however the Category shows me the list but when I click on one of them to show me the products inside each one, does not display anything.

Here is my ProductsController.cs.

```
public ActionResult Index(string category, string subcategory, string search, string sortBy, int? page){... }
```

On the RouteConfig.cs I have:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductsCreate",
        url: "Products/Create",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Create" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductsbySubCategorybyPage",
        url: "Products/{subcategory}/Page{page}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductsbyCategorybyPage",
        url: "Products/{category}/Page{page}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductsbyPage",
        url: "Products/Page{page}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductsbySubCategory",
        url: "Products/{subcategory}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductsbyCategory",
        url: "Products/{category}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" }
    );                       

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductsIndex",
        url: "Products",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail what is the code used/view that is displayed when the `Productsbycategory` route is activated? (i.e., "when I click on one of them..." is ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProductsbyCategorybyPage` is overwritten by `ProductsbySubCategorybyPage`.
When ASP.NET is trying to parse the incoming URL, it will stop with the find match, and URL like `Products/A/Page3` will be passed through the `ProductsbySubCategorybyPage` route. Routing module does not know what do you prefer `A` to be, subcategory or category. You need to refactor your `RegisterRoutes` method to use unique route masks. Like `Products/SubCategory/{subcategory}` and `Products/Category/{category}` for example.